# How to read Query Params in fasthttp without URL decoding

Tags: go, fasthttp

I am processing a `GET` request in Go using [fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp).

The query parameter `test` in this request is `.%2A%2Ftoday%2F.%2A`.

I am using POSTMAN to create the request, and the URL generated is:

```
http://localhost:3000/apiname/?test=.%252A%252Ftoday%252F.%252A
```

`ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("test")` gives me  `.*/today/.*` instead of the original `.%2A%2Ftoday%2F.%2A`

I know I cannot partially encode/decode the request URL. Is there any way to get the original param as is?

Comment: Maybe no, what is the use-case of this? A hack is again encode.

Comment: How can i encode a string in Golang ?

Comment: You can do this way `url.QueryEscape(".*/today/.*")` using `net/url` package

Comment: @Eklavya Thanks! You can post this as an answer , I'll accept.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure? I've just tested it and I'm getting the result you want.

This is the minimal working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/fasthttp/router"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func Test(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    ctx.Response.SetBodyString(string(ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("test")))
    fmt.Println(string(ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("test")))
}

func main() {

    r := router.New()
    r.GET("/test", Test)
    log.Fatal(fasthttp.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", r.Handler))
}
```

This is the command line output after the GET request:

```
$ go run main.go                                                                                                                
.%2A%2Ftoday%2F.%2A
```

and this is the response in Postman:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be passing double encoded param.